# How to reformat a displayed date?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am working on saving emails and attachments.

I need to figure out how to reformat the default date display my code is coming up with.  Currently it results in mm/dd/yyyy.

This date is going to be in the file path for where the email or attachment will be saved. I need it to be in the format of yyyy-mm-dd since I cannot include slashes in file paths.

My test code to learn to do this is as follows:

```
Sub testdate()
'Get Friday's Date
Dim NextFriday As Date
NextFriday = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbFriday)

'Popup
MsgBox "Next Friday's Date is " & NextFriday
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `Format$`:

```
Sub testdate()
    'Get Friday's Date
    Dim NextFriday As Date
    NextFriday = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbFriday)

    'Popup
    MsgBox "Next Friday's Date is " & Format$(NextFriday, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Sub
```